# Nativescript Angular, cannot backToPreviousPage

Tags: angular, nativescript

in my Nativescript with angular app, I cannot go back to the previous page if another page is added to the stack.

So im basicly navigating to my `chat-window` component from my `main-component` in code like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/chat-window'], {transition: {name: 'slideLeft'}});
```

At this point my Actionbar shows the back button which is working fine! It leads me back to the `main-component` 
Then im navigating from the action bar of my `chat-window` to `chat-history` like this:

```
<ActionItem [nsRouterLink]="['/chat-history']" pageTransition="slideLeft" icon="res://notification"></ActionItem>
```

When i press the back button now, it is going back to `chat-window` like expected. And there is another Back button now which should lead to the main component. But what was working before is not working anymore. I get no errors but i can press the back button as much as I want, it does not work.

Why is it not possible to goBackToPreviousPage two time sin a row on a stack of pages? Or am I doing it wrong?

Here my Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [

    {path: '', redirectTo: '/auth-start', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'auth-start', component: AuthStartComponent},
    { path: "tabview", component: TabviewComponent,
        children: [
            {path: "home", component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'homeOutlet'},
            {path: "chat-rooms", component: ChatRoomsComponent, outlet: 'chatRoomsOutlet'},
            {path: "user-list", component: UserListComponent, outlet: 'userListOutlet'},
            {path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent, outlet: 'profileOutlet'}
        ] },
    {path: "register", component: RegisterComponent},
    {path: "login", component: LoginComponent},
    {path: "chat-window", component: ChatWindowComponent},
    {path: "chat-history", component: ChatHistoryComponent}
];
```

My Back Button in the Actionbar:

```
<NavigationButton *ngIf="CanGoBack"  text="Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" (tap)="onGoBack()"></NavigationButton>
```

related code:

```
constructor(private rExtensions: RouterExtensions) {
  }


  get CanGoBack() {
    return this.rExtensions.canGoBackToPreviousPage();
  }

  onGoBack() {
    this.rExtensions.backToPreviousPage();
  }
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: It should be possible to go back as many times as you navigated forward on a frame (page-router-outlet), so `this.router.backToPreviousPage()` should work. Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Cant do that at the moment. But would you recommend to inject the routerExtensions once in a service and then access this one in all my components? At the moment im injecting it in every component where i need it. Is that wrong?

Comment: No, injecting it on every component is not an issue.

Comment: I added my routes. Does that help? Im navigating from chat-rooms to chat-window to chat-history and then want to go back to chat-room after pressing the back button 2 times like described

Comment: Sometimes I am getting the following notice in the console: `Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?` could that be the reason?

Comment: Could be but I'm not very sure until I see some related code. Are you customising the back button (NavigationButton) tap event by any chance?

Comment: I edited the post and added my back button and the related code. I figured its not just I cannot go back. I also cant navigate to any other page forward after i clicked "back" on the chat-history. So im basicly stuck on "chat-window". I also tried to avoid the ngZone error. but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Is this a platform specific issue? Unlike Android, `NavigationButton` is handled by default on iOS. If it's iOS you are facing issues with, try commenting the `NavigationButton` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189917/discussion-between-xdrago-and-manoj).